# Careers 2.0 profile: truly hidden?

Tags: discussion, jobs, privacy

The Careers 2.0 "My Profile" page allows you set "Public view" to "hidden" and "employer view" to "blocked" (in the detail/editing view the text is "Block all messages and searches")—does that really mean that my presence on stack overflow careers is "hidden" completely, or just that potential employers/searchers can't actually see the details of my profile?

The distinction I'm making is that in Facebook, for example, marketers can't see your actual profile, but it is possible to find people (and find out things about people) just by playing with the search settings until you have a small handful, and then by elimination deriving answers about that sample through further detailed searches—is this the same, or is having your profile blocked really information-leak-proof?

This is more of an idle curiosity question than one of practical importance, obviously (given that I'm here posting on meta about it, with my public profile :)).

Comment: The other question was downvoted because it was very silly and based on weird misinterpretations of the invitation email. This is at least a reasonable question.

Comment: You can never have less than 1 reputation point. But keep posting questions that read like rants, and we'll see if we can't get you down to 1.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I have tried to explain why my previous "question" (intended as "feedback") was there - if you know of a better place it should go, I would love to know. If you consider it offensive, I would be happy to delete it. My somewhat snide reference to reputation loss above was only triggered by the flurry of downvotes which came as a surprise to me, as I also tried to explain what my post was doing there.

Comment: I have never tried to make the point that you posted either question in the wrong place. Meta is indeed the place for this type of question/discussion. The problem is that the other question reads like a bit of a rant to me, particularly a misinformed one. The Careers people are offering you a paid-for service for free, based on your activity on Stack Overflow. If you aren't interested in using it, then you're under no obligation to do so. I thought that part was a little bit offensive. Beyond all of that, though, get used to downvotes on Meta. They mean something different here.

Comment: Fair enough, I still feel a bit weird about a system where 1) negative feedback "costs" the person providing the feedback and 2) all feedback must be public. Don't get me wrong, I think StackOverflow is amazing in so many ways - something about this careers thing just rubbed me up the wrong way I guess. And this isn't quite true: "The Careers people are offering you a paid-for service for free, based on your activity on Stack Overflow"; the "careers people" are monetizing users, just like facebook does. The only difference here is that they're asking for permission/offering additional perks.

Comment: (disclosure: I was being an idiot, there was in fact an email address for careers at the stackoverflow domain, and I just missed it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you block the employer view and hide your public profile, you are truly hidden from view. You will not show up in searches (not even as a statistic) and nobody will be able to see your information.

Comment: Thanks Korneel, that's great - after all my whining I suspect I'm really going to like the Careers 2.0 functionality :)